# IBM SmartCloud Control Desk REST API

Tags: rest, maximo, tivoli

I'm trying to write a program to access the SCCD REST API, but can't find any documentation online. I'd like to know the URLs I have to call. So for example to access a persons details I call :

```
/maxrest/rest/os/person
```

But I can't find any other URIs or any documentation of that API. The only [thing](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v50r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mbs.doc%2Fgp_intfrmwk%2Frest_api%2Fc_rest_overview.html) I found, doesn't mention the URLs. I want something like [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/worlodep/v3r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worlodep.doc%2Fra%2Frar_group.html) just for SCCD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to the IBM Support, it seems there is indeed no documentation available.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a loooong time and it's probably not relevant for this person, but I did find a better answer than "no".

Here's the link:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWT9A_7.5.3/com.ibm.mif.doc/gp_intfrmwk/rest_api/c_rest_overview.html

Comment: If you check my question this is exactly what I linked (just of a previous versions).